# Synchronize issues has encountered - Sonar integration error in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, integration, sonarqube, synchronize

Steps followed,

-> Installed sonar plugin in Eclipse 4.2.2 by following the steps from - http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/static-code-analysis-and

-> Build project with mvn sonar:sonar command.

-> Right clicked project in Eclipse to associate to sonar and get the below error in "Problem Occurred popup"

**'Synchronize issues' has encountered a problem. 
Error during issue query
org.sonar.wsclient.issue.IssueQuery@d6cd19**

How to fix this? Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to [SonarLint for Eclipse](http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/index.html). Much more faster than the SonarQube Eclipse plugin, it will make you able to run SonarQube analysis without the need to get connected to SonarQube server.

If you want to connect to a SonarQube server anyway in order to synchronize analysis configuration, it is also possible but not required. ;)